# Can be MPI implemented on bare-metal ARM or on any other kind of multicore microcontroller?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, microcontroller, bare-metal

My goal is to somehow use PLUTO (a C to C compiler which automatically parallelize the input code and produce C code with MPI function calls (also with OpenMP pragmas)) on a C code and use the output C code with MPI calls on a bare-metal microcontroller even if it mean I have to implement MPI functions and other things like a basic scheduler to that particular architect. But could it be achieved without an OS (not even RTOS)?

I want to run it only one CPU so not in a cluster. I know there is OpenMP for that use. But that still using fork() and join() so basically posix threads which require OS too.

Or is there any other API which suitable for microcontroller parallelization, but without OS?

Comment: As far as Open MPI is concerned, `pthreads` are (among other things) a requirement.

Comment: Have you tried to cross compile open MPI using a RTOS with a posix interface (NuttX, RIOT OS or Zephyr should do the trick) for arm  ?